# Firebird SQL statement with UNION gives data type unknown even with cast

Tags: sql, union, firebird, type-conversion, firebird1.5

I have the following query where in one of the union queries, a field has to be 0, and in the other part it gives an average from a subquery.
I have to use a SELECT subquery. I can not use JOINS as it will yield doubled records in the result set  (the actual query is far more complex):

```
SELECT A,B, CAST(0 as FLOAT) as C
 FROM TABLE1
 WHERE CONDITION=0
UNION
SELECT T1.A, T1.B, (SELECT AVG(T3.C+T3.E) FROM T3 WHERE T3.A = T1.A) as C
 FROM TABLE1 T1
 WHERE T1.CONDITION=1
```

All fields are Float types in the database, but I still get data type unknown.

Is there a way to know which data type `AVG(T3.C+T3.E)` has?

My workaround is to use `(T1.C*0) as C` instead of `CAST(0 as FLOAT) as C`.

Comment: What version of Firebird, and what is the dialect of your database (1 or 3)?

Comment: Firebird 1.5 dialect 3

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: why u use UNION DISTINCT instead of UNION ALL ? you force Firebird to check if it can delete repeating rows....

Comment: Firebird_v2.1.7.ReleaseNotes.pdf  page 68: "Improved Type Coercion in UNIONs: Automatic resolution of the data type of the result of an aggregation over values of compatible data types, such
as case expressions and columns at the same position in a union query expression, now uses smarter rules."  -  bad luck staying with 1.5...

Comment: Perhaps just fix the type in both parts? `SELECT T1.A, T1.B, CAST((SELECT AVG(T3.C+T3.E) FROM T3 WHERE T3.A = T1.A) as FLOAT) as C ....`

Comment: I'm curious to know, why still Firebird 1.5? The last update of that version was 13 years ago, and there have been a lot fixes and changes (including fixes of security-related bugs!) since that time.

Comment: we internally still have some BDE-based self-made CRM, that works with 1.5 still. I do not know details, but attempts to run that program and DB on 2.1 failed

Answer (score 2):

One method is to avoid the `union` at all:

```
SELECT A, B,
       (CASE WHEN CONDITION = 0 THEN CAST(0 as FLOAT)
             ELSE (SELECT AVG(T3.C+T3.E) FROM T3 WHERE T3.A = T1.A) 
        END) as C
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CONDITION IN (0, 1);
```